# Sails configuration and Global Scope

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am a relatively novice JS developer and slowly "learning the ropes".

Recently I read some guidelines that suggest using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to prevent pollution of global scope (the guidelines where for angular apps but...) .

Now considering the sails configuration system, I see a lot of examples with "free floating" code, e.g.:

```
// sails/config/log.js
var Winston = require('winston');
var customLogger =  new winston.Logger();
// configure logger

module.exports = {
    custom: customLogger,
    level: 'info',
}
```

If I understand that concept, customLogger/winston are added to the global scope.

Am I correct?

I believe that if I want to do anything "significant" I must write some code in configuration files - and in these cases, I assume general practice rules should apply...

Should I use IIFE in these places?

For example:

```
// sails/config/log.js
(function() {
    var Winston = require('winston');
    var customLogger =  new winston.Logger();
    // configure logger

    module.exports = {
        custom: customLogger,
        level: 'info',
    }
}());
```

Are there any pros/cons with this? Is it important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question.

Node.js and browser/front-end JavaScript global scopes are not working the same way.

In a **browser environment**, you've got a global scope (known as `window`) that contains everything declared in your different scripts:

```html
<script>
 var a = 'hello';
 console.log('first script');
</script>

<script>
 var b = 'world';
 console.log(a, b);
 console.log(window.a, window.b);
</script>
```

An IIFE "protects against polluting the global environment" because what you declare in it doesn't get to the global scope.

```html
<script>
 (function () {
  var a = 'hello';
  console.log('first script');
 })();
</script>

<script>
 (function () {
  console.log(a); // a is not defined
 })();
</script>

<script>
 (function () {
  console.log(window.a); // undefined
 })();
</script>
```

You can take advantage of this behavior to organize your front-end code by using the [Module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/).

In a **Node.js environment**, you can declare whatever you want in different files and it won't be accessible from the others unless you want it to by using `module.exports`.

For example, you can do this:

```
// module-a.js
var a = 'hello';
module.exports = a + ' world';

// index.js
var moduleA = require('./module-a');
console.log(moduleA); // 'hello world'
console.log(a); // a is not defined
console.log(moduleA.a); // undefined
```

So in your Sails project (which gets executed with Node.js), **you don't need to use IIFEs and should use `module.exports`** which is totally sufficient.

[More on this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and examples... to re-iterate, in nodejs a file execution is kind of it's own "sandbox" or scope and anything not attached to module.exports is "local"?

Comment: Exactly! By the way, you can access your "local" scope with the `global` keyword (e.g. `global.a` would contain `'hello'` in the module-a.js file)